# Method with all parameters as default values is not the same as method without parameter

Tags: scala

Why call to method whose all parameters has default values is not the same than calling a method without parameter in scala?

Example:

```
scala> def a(a:Int=1)=print(a)
a: (a: Int)Unit

scala> def b=print(1)
b: Unit

scala> a
<console>:13: error: missing argument list for method a
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type 
is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `a _` or `a(_)` 
instead of `a`.
   a
   ^

scala> b
1
```

However

```
scala>a()
1
```

works ok. 
Shouldn't be the same call?

Answer (score 1):

**Scala** enable **Arity-0**(a) method to omit parentheses.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#arity-0

Comment: Yes, the question is why a method whose all parameters has default values is not considered a Arity-0?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of at least one problem caused by not needing to write parenthesis. Consider the following:

```
val xs = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
def myFunc(x: Int = 42) = 2 * x
val ys = xs.map(myFunc)
```

Eta expansion is happening in my example, method is lifted into function. But if it was possible to invoke function with default parameters this way, syntax would be ambigous at least in this case. (I know that here invocation would lead to wrong argument type of map function, so in theory it is possible to resolve this ambiguity here, but it would mean that type of expression would have impact on the syntax interpretation, which is handled before type-checking in any language i know)

Comment: I don't see the ambiguity. In this case you pass the parameter to myFunc so it doesn't get the default value

Answer (score 1):

If you don't add a parenthesis after `a`, that will have several meanings.

1. `a(): Unit`
2. `a(_): Int => Unit`

Which one do you mean? Hence it force you to add parenthesis.

Comment: I think it may be a() because I am not passing any parameter. What means a(_)?

Comment: `a(_)` means `(x: Int) => a(x)`, a function of type `Int=>Unit`. It is one of the Scala language syntax.

Comment: So, there is no a problem. a can be interpreted as the call and a _ as the address  of the function

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, a method can have zero or more parameter lists, each of which has zero or more parameters. If you want to call a method, you have to supply matching argument lists with matching arguments to the parameters and parameter lists.

In your case, you defined the method with one parameter list, ergo you need to call it with one argument list.

> Shouldn't be the same call?

No, they are not the same. The first call has zero argument lists, the second call has one argument list. That's different.

There *are* some cases where Scala lets you call methods with a single empty parameter list by supplying no argument lists. The reason for this is simple convenience: you want to call Java getters (which are defined with an empty parameter list) the same way as Scala getters (which are defined without a parameter list). But, this doesn't work *in general*.